# Flask accepting file from HTML form - Bad Request

Tags: python, html, flask

Edited to include the first answers input:

My HTML form looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="http://localhost:5000/upload_candidates" method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="csv_file" accept="*">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

the Flask endpoint looks like this:

```
@app.route('/upload_candidates', methods=['POST'])
def upload_candidates():
    print('this worked')
    file = request.files['file']
    print('did this work?')
    x = file.read()
    print(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(threaded=True, debug=True)
```

I'm getting an error: `The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.`

In the terminal:

```
 * Detected change in '..../hello.py', reloading
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 238-076-488
this worked
```

In the network console:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:5000/upload_candidates
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 BAD REQUEST
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:5000
```

It seems like it doesn't like the `file = request.files['file']` line.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One thing you are doing wrong is not using `debug=True` in your application. Try changing `app.run()` to `app.run(debug=True)` to see a more helpful diagnostic message.

Comment: I do have it enabled :-(

Comment: Then I apologize for my snarky comment.

Comment: hah, all good. I just want to figure out why this isn't working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<form>` is missing an `enctype` attribute:

```
<form action="http://localhost:5000/upload_candidates" 
             method="POST" 
             enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Also, it appears that you are referencing a `request.files` member by the wrong name. Try this:

```
file = request.files['csv_file']
```

Comment: Then please [edit] your question to include a short, complete program that demonstrates the error. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: Nope. I was looking for a complete, reproducible example. But your `print` output helped. See my recent edit.